# Fast way to convolve a non-centered gaussian with a healpy map?

Tags: python, astronomy, healpy

I have a healpix map (nside=256) and I am trying to convolve it with a gaussian, which is not centered, this is, simulating an offset in the 'telescope pointing'. Is there an easy way of doing this?

I know `healpy.smoothing' works for usual gaussians, but have not been able to find anything for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you convolve the map with `hp.smoothing` and now you have a uniformly smoothed map.

Then when you observe it to turn it into a timestream, you add an offset to your pointing, so instead of picking the "right" pixel, you pick instead one of the nearby pixels.

So let's say you have `theta` and `phi` and pointing errors `dtheta` and `dphi`, you do:

```
pix = hp.ang2pix(256, theta+dtheta, phi+dphi)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have to give it a thought, since I am not sure that it would be equivalent? Specially if the simulated sky that I am observing is not-uniform (i.e. I'm simulating a full sky in radiofrequencies, not only some specific components). Do you have an intuition on this?

Comment: Yes, I have given it a thought and it has the same effect. Thank you very much for your help!